# modifying cqlsh prompt to get unique identifier

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Currently when I start up cqlsh, I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-83-106:~$ cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

I want to be able to change

> cqlsh>

not something unique, like

> ubuntu@ip-172-31-83-106>

and each time I run a query, the prompt will remain. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CQLSH has very limited support for customization of the prompt. The only custom thing that you can bring into prompt is the string that should be passed via `CQLSH_PROMPT` environment variable and that will be printed before `cqlsh>` string (see [sources](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/bin/cqlsh.py#L426))

For example, if you start your CQLSH as

```
CQLSH_PROMPT="$(whoami)@$(hostname)" cqlsh
```

then you'll gets something like this:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-83-106
cqlsh>
```

but that's all what you can do.